# Change image appearance based on user actions?

Tags: java, gwt, java-canvas

I used `applyTo(image)` on a `AbstractImagePrototype` in the past. But now resources are mainly created with a `@Resource AbstractImagePrototype` line.

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/AbstractImagePrototype.html

> The applyTo(Image) method provides an efficient way to replace the
>   contents of an existing Image. This is useful in cases where an image
>   changes its appearance based on a user's action. Instead of creating
>   two Image objects then alternately hiding/showing them, one can use
>   the applyTo(Image) method of two AbstractImagePrototype objects to
>   transform a single Image object between two (or more) visual
>   representations.

But now it seems better to use a `ClientBundle` with `@Source ImageResource`.
Unfortunately this ImageResource does not provide a `applyTo(image)` method. What to I have to change to have the same functionality to just replace an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's [`Image#setResource(ImageResource)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Image.html#setResource%28com.google.gwt.resources.client.ImageResource%29) and [`AbstractImageResource.create(ImageResource)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/AbstractImagePrototype.html#create%28com.google.gwt.resources.client.ImageResource%29), and [many other ways](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/resources/client/class-use/ImageResource.html) to use an `ImageResource`.

Comment: setResource works great and seems to be the equivalent to applyTo().